# Why would /Qvec-report:2 return nothing ? (MSVC 2012)

Tags: visual-c++

I tried the /Qvec-report:2 option to see if the MSVC auto-vectorizer would be any use. Unfortunately, I didn't get any result, positive nor negative:

```
>  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.60610.1 for x86
1>  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>  
1>  cl /c /Zi /nologo- /W3 /WX- /O2 /Ob2 /Oi /Oy /GL /D WIN32 /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D NDEBUG /D _LIB /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm- /EHsc /MD /GS /Gy /arch:SSE2 /fp:fast /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Yu"stdafx.h" /Fp"Release\(redacted).pch" /Fo"Release\\" /Fd"Release\vc110.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /errorReport:prompt  /Qvec-report:2 (redacted).cpp
1>cl : Command line warning D9035: option 'nologo-' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
1>  
1>  (redacted).cpp
1>
1>Build succeeded.
```

I expected a message similar to

```
--- Analyzing function: main 
c:\source.cpp(4) : loop vectorized 
c:\source.cpp(5) : loop not vectorized due to reason '1200'
```

Comment: No idea - it works fine for me for both /QVec and /QPar. I see this is a Release build, which is correct. Did you build or rebuild?

Comment: Build, rebuild, switch to x64 - dead as a dodo.

Comment: Well it should vectorize by default, but you might try adding /QPar in case that's relevant (my project has both).

Comment: Actually, I seem to remember that /arch:SSE2 affects it (can't find ref at the mo) - can you remove that option?

Comment: /arch:SSE2 is the first step above /arch:IA32, and /arch:IA32 doesn't allow vectorization. So I need that option, at least on x86.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cause turned out to be the `/GL` option. With link-time code generation, the compile step becomes just a parsing step, and does not include any vectorization. Since that step is entirely missing, no report (positive nor negative) is generated at compile time.

The linker can now emit vectorization steps instead. This happens even if the LTCG object files were placed in a library.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Visual Studio 2012's Auto-Vectorization Cookbook](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/00/00/01/04/99/3007.Auto-Vectorizer-08-Cookbook.pdf), either `/O2` or `/O2 /GL` will enable auto-vectorization.