# Why would function templates not be analyzed by MSVC12's auto-vectorizer?

Tags: templates, visual-c++, parallel-processing, msvc12, auto-vectorization

Function templates are not seen by the auto-vectorization or the auto-parallelizer (/Qpar) engine in VS2013.

For example, this code:

```
void foo::someFunc(int a)
{
    int myArray[1000000];

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
       myArray[i] = i+1;
    }
}
```

seems to be recognized and I get the appropriate output from /Qvec-report:2 and /Qpar-report:2:

```
foo.cpp

--- Analyzing function: void __cdecl foo::someFunc(int) __ptr64
c:\visual studio 2013\projects\autovectest\autovectest\foo.cpp(18) : info C5001: loop vectorized
c:\visual studio 2013\projects\autovectest\autovectest\foo.cpp(18) : info C5012: loop not parallelized due to reason '1007'
AutoVecTest.vcxproj -> c:\visual studio 2013\Projects\AutoVecTest\x64\Debug\AutoVecTest.dll
```

But, as soon as I turn `someFunc()` into a function template:

```
template <class T>
void foo::someFunc(T a)
{
    int myArray[1000000];

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        myArray[i] = i+1;
    }
}
```

I get nothing from the auto-vectorizer or the auto-parallelizer in the logs:

```
foo.cpp
AutoVecTest.vcxproj -> c:\visual studio 2013\Projects\AutoVecTest\x64\Debug\AutoVecTest.dll
```

I am not using /GL as stated in [Why would /Qvec-report:2 return nothing ? (MSVC 2012)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380639/why-would-qvec-report2-return-nothing-msvc-2012)

Comment: Are you actually calling the function? `1>--- Analyzing function: void __cdecl someFunc<int>(int)
1>c:\temp\test\test.cpp(321) : info C5001: loop vectorized
1>c:\temp\test\test.cpp(321) : info C5012: loop not parallelized due to reason '1007'`

Comment: I suppose I'm not in my sample code.  But I am with my real life code.  Let me adjust my sample code and report back

Comment: Success with my sample code!   If I call a templated funciton (ie ```int a; someFunc(a);``` or explicitly instantiate the function (```template void someFunc(int a)```), I get the auto-vectorizor/parallalizer messages.

Comment: Looking at the disassembly, I guess my sample code isn't accurately reflecting my real life code issue.  

In my sample code, if I do not call someFunc() or explicitly instantiate someFunc(), someFunc() does not show up in the obj file (using dumpbin /disasm).

However, in my real life code, my functions appear in the obj file, so the template functions are at least being created.  So I'm not sure that's the issue...

Comment: Ok, I figured out the discrepancy between the sample code and my real life code.  My real code's header file had a ```#pragma optimize("gt", on)``` that was never turned off, so it was erroneously auto-vectorizing some functions that it shouldn't have been.  Once I added the ```#pragma optimize("", on)``` after the intended function, the auto-vectorizer behaved as it should have.

Answer (score 0):

1. As Retired Ninja pointed out, make sure your function template is actually called or instantiated.
2. Make sure the proper optimization compile flags are enabled.  YMMV here, but [Visual Studio 2012's Auto-Vectorization Cookbook](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/00/00/01/04/99/3007.Auto-Vectorizer-08-Cookbook.pdf) says `/O2` or `/O2 /GL` will work.  Another user discovered `/GL` did not work for them ([Why would /Qvec-report:2 return nothing ? (MSVC 2012)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380639/why-would-qvec-report2-return-nothing-msvc-2012)).  Using `#pragma("gt", on)` enabled the auto-vectorizer for me.